# Is there any food restrictions after dog bite

Tags: food-safety, animal-bites

When a street dog bites a human, Are there any food restrictions while being treated?

I heard we should't eat spicy foods and non veg , is it another myth ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is myth. According to the [World Health Organization](http://www.who.int/rabies/resources/SEA_CD_278_FAQs_Rabies.pdf):

> There are no dietary restrictions during the course  of vaccination.